# Area of rhombus given circumradii of its contained triangles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Here is a question I came across

> Find the area of rhombus ABCD given that the radii of the circles
>   circumscribed around triangles ABD and ACD are 12.5 and 25,
>   respectively.

With the diagonals of the rhombus perpendicularly bisecting each other, let $a$ be half of diagonal BD and $b$ half of diagonal AC. Thus, the sides of the rhombus are $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ long.

The area of any triangle can be expressed as $\frac{\text{product of side lengths}}{\text{4 multiplied by the circumradius}}$. Thus, the area $\Delta ABC$ is $\frac{2b (a^2 + b^2)}{4(12.5)}$, while the area of $\Delta ABD$ is $\frac{2a (a^2 + b^2)}{4(25)}$. These two areas are equal since both of the said triangles are half of the rhombus. Setting these two expressions equal to each other and simplifying gives $b = 2a$.

I've been stuck here for the past few hours. I'm blatantly missing something here. What's the next step?

Answer (score 1):

we denote the Areas of the triangles by $A_1$ and $A_2$ and the diagonals by $e$ and $f$: then we have $$A_1=\frac{a^2f}{50}$$ and $$A_2=\frac{a^2e}{100}$$ also we get
$$A_1=\frac{1}{2}a^2\sin(\alpha)$$ and $$A_2=\frac{1}{2}a^2\sin(180^{\circ}-\alpha)$$
from here we get $$f=\frac{1}{2}e$$ with $$e^2+f^2=4a^2$$ we get $$e=\frac{4}{\sqrt{5}}a$$ and $$f=\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}a$$ and then we have $$\tan\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}$$ can you finish now?

Comment: it is the Theorem of Pythagoras in one right triangle $$\frac{e^2}{4}+\frac{f^2}{4}=a^2$$

Comment: It just occurred to me that $e^2 + f^2 = 4a^2$ is just the parallelogram law!

However, what's next? I still keep getting the stuff I got from earlier calculations.

Comment: hi Lucas the next steps i posted above

Comment: I meant I'm stuck at $\tan \frac{\alpha}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$. Any hint?

Comment: i denoted the angle situated by $A$ with $\alpha$ the diagonale $AC$ is the internal angle bisector thus $$\tan(\frac{\alpha}{2})=\frac{\frac{e}{2}}{\frac{f}{2}}$$

Comment: Yes, I already saw that too. What''s after? (Sorry, I should have said this earlier). I get the area of the rhombus to be $\frac{4}{5} a^2$. I'm looking for a numerical value.

Comment: you can compute the area as$$A=\frac{ef}{2}$$

Comment: and use that $$e=25\sin(\alpha)$$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Let $\angle DAB=\alpha$, $R_1=12.5$, $R_2=2R_1=25$.

Using the general formula for the area of triangle $ABC$
in terms of its curcumradius $R$ and sinuses of its angles $A,B,C$
\begin{align} 
S_{ABC}&=2R^2\sin A\sin B\sin C
\tag{1}\label{1}
,
\end{align}

we have

\begin{align} 
S_{ABCD}&=2S_{ABD}=2S_{ACD}
\tag{2}\label{2}
,\\
S_{ABD}&=2R_1^2\sin\alpha\sin^2(90^\circ-\tfrac\alpha2)
=2R_1^2\sin\alpha\cos^2\tfrac\alpha2
\tag{3}\label{3}
,\\
S_{ACD}&=2R_2^2\sin(180^\circ-\alpha)\sin^2\tfrac\alpha2
=2R_2^2\sin\alpha\sin^2\tfrac\alpha2
\tag{4}\label{4}
,
\end{align}

hence we must have

\begin{align}
\tan\tfrac\alpha2&=\frac{R_1}{R_2}=\frac{12.5}{25}=\frac12
,
\end{align}
and the rest is straightforward:

\begin{align}
\sin\alpha&=\frac{2\tan\tfrac\alpha2}{1+\tan^2\tfrac\alpha2}=\frac45
. 
\end{align}

Since given $R_2=2R_1$, we can rewrite \eqref{4} as

\begin{align} 
S_{ACD}
&=
2(2R_1)^2\sin\alpha\sin^2\tfrac\alpha2
=
8R_1^2\sin\alpha\sin^2\tfrac\alpha2
\tag{6}\label{6}
,
\end{align}

and avoid calculation of 
$\sin\tfrac\alpha2$
and
$\cos\tfrac\alpha2$

\begin{align}
4S_{ABD}+S_{ACD}&=5S_{ABD}
\\
&=8R_1^2\sin\alpha(\sin^2\tfrac\alpha2+\cos^2\tfrac\alpha2)
=8R_1^2\cdot\frac45
,\\
S_{ABD}&=\frac{32R_1^2}{25}=200
,
\end{align}

and the answer is
\begin{align}
S_{ABCD}&=400
.
\end{align}